# get the row details of other table from another server and merge it to your query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),
CAST(abs(SUM(
CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] in ('5010', '5011','5020','5030')
and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'BANQUITO' 
THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)+ 
SUM(
CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] between '5041' and '5047'
and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'BANQUITO'  
THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)) as MONEY),1),'.00','') As Net,
replace(convert(NVARCHAR,[Posting Date],110),'-','/')as PostingDate
from [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry]  
where [Posting Date] between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-01-30 00:00:00'  
Group by [Posting Date];
```

this will result into

```
 COLA | COLB 
 row  | row
```

i would like to add another column from this query

```
select count(distinct checkno) as  TCOUNT
from [10.0.0.165].[MenuEngg].[dbo].GNDSale  
where dob between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-01-30 00:00:00'
and branchcode in ('037') and branchcode in  ('037')and type in ('31','19')
```

where it should give me cola colb colc, i dont know how will i match [global dimension 1 code] into another database which is using [branch code]? to get or merge them and come up with this result

```
COLA | COLB | COLC
row  | row  | row
```

Comment: sqlserver, its 2 database from 2 different server, and it doesnt execute if i dont include [

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.Net,a.PostingDate,
    (
      SELECT count(DISTINCT checkno) AS TCOUNT
       FROM [10.0.0.165].[MenuEngg].[dbo].GNDSale
       WHERE dob BETWEEN '2016-01-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-30 00:00:00'
         AND branchcode IN ('037')
         AND branchcode IN ('037')
         AND TYPE IN ('31','19') 
    ) as COLC
FROM
  ( SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 
        CAST(abs(SUM( CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] IN ('5010', '5011','5020','5030')
            AND [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'BANQUITO' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)+ SUM( CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] BETWEEN '5041' AND '5047'
                AND [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'BANQUITO' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)) AS MONEY),1),'.00',''
                   ) AS Net,
           replace(convert(NVARCHAR,[Posting Date],110),'-','/') AS PostingDate
   FROM [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry]
   WHERE [Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-30 00:00:00'
   GROUP BY [Posting Date] 
   ) a
```

Comment: problem when i try to run a 1 month filter it would result to a multiple and same  COLC per row